# Column name referenced for relation not exist - ManyToMany relationship Symfony Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a little problem with Doctrine and Symfony 5.4. I've searched on StackOverflow and on the doc, but every solution seems that is not correctly for me.

I have 3 class: Lang, State, OrderState. Last one is join with Lang and State through id_state and id_lang with a ManyToMany association relation ship.

When i execute the schema validate, i get the classic error. Honestly i don't understand why.

```
    Mapping
-------

 [FAIL] The entity-class App\Entity\OrderState mapping is invalid:
 * The referenced column name 'id_state' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'App\Entity\OrderState'.
 * The referenced column name 'id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'App\Entity\Lang'.


Database
--------


In MissingColumnException.php line 15:
                                                                                   
  Column name "id_state" referenced for relation from App\Entity\OrderState towa   
  rds App\Entity\State does not exist.
```

State.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\StateRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=StateRepository::class)
 */
class State
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id_state;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $label;


    public function getIdState(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_state;
    }

    public function getLabel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->label;
    }

    public function setLabel(string $label): self
    {
        $this->label = $label;

        return $this;
    }

   
}
```

Lang.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\LangRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=LangRepository::class)
 */
class Lang
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id_lang;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lang;

    public function getIdLang(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_lang;
    }

    public function setIdLang(int $id_lang): self
    {
        $this->id_lang = $id_lang;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLang(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lang;
    }

    public function setLang(string $lang): self
    {
        $this->lang = $lang;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and OrderState.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\OrderStateRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=OrderStateRepository::class)
 */
class OrderState
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=State::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_state", referencedColumnName="id_state")
     */
    private $id_state;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Lang::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_lang", referencedColumnName="id_lang")
     */
    private $id_lang;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $state;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id_state = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->id_lang = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, State>
     */
    public function getIdState(): Collection
    {
        return $this->id_state;
    }

    public function addIdState(State $idState): self
    {
        if (!$this->id_state->contains($idState)) {
            $this->id_state[] = $idState;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeIdState(State $idState): self
    {
        $this->id_state->removeElement($idState);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Lang>
     */
    public function getIdLang(): Collection
    {
        return $this->id_lang;
    }

    public function addIdLang(Lang $idLang): self
    {
        if (!$this->id_lang->contains($idLang)) {
            $this->id_lang[] = $idLang;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeIdLang(Lang $idLang): self
    {
        $this->id_lang->removeElement($idLang);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getState(): ?string
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    public function setState(?string $state): self
    {
        $this->state = $state;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of mistakes in entities so please try to create entities from the `Maker Bundle` it will create a proper entity for you. https://symfony.com/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/current/index.html

Comment: @RaviDamasiya yes, i used this one but i still get this error. And also, is possible to create an entity without a primary key?

Comment: @s.lafrag You always need a primary key.  As suggested, use `make:entity` to create two very simple entities with a many to many relation.  Then add a third entity and create an additional m:n relation.  Having a working example will save you quite a bit of time in the long run.

Comment: Yes, you can create entity without primary key

Comment: @RaviDamasiya How exactly would you go about creating a Doctrine entity without a primary key?  Remember that composite primary keys are still primary keys.

Comment: @Cerad check this project and understand it's best practice project of symfony https://github.com/symfony/demo

Comment: @RaviDamasiya I think we got our wires crossed a bit.  I though you literally meant being able to map (i.e. create) an entity without designating a primary key.  Which would be interesting.  You are simply saying that you can instantiate an entity without a value for the id property and have the database generate it typically via autoinc or sequential column types.  Not sure which question the OP was asking.  They seem determined to to their own thing anyways.

Comment: @Cerad sorry that we can not create an entity without a primary key. You are right.